# Can you statically set a Header and it's value when setting up an HTTP Proxy using AWS Api Gateway endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am creating an http proxy using AWS Api Gateway.  I would like to hard code some of the headers and their values to be forwarded as part of the request.  I thought this might be possible in the 'Integration Request' portion of the proxy setup, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm trying to pass an `Authorization` header with an oauth key.  I don't want to share this key with clients that have access to this service, since I will only provide a subset of access to users of this specific endpoint.

Comment: Do you mean request or response header?

Comment: @GarySharpe Did you solved this problem?

Comment: @svlada, I haven't been able to confirm whether the solution below given by Bryce Thomas works.  Give that a try, and please let me know if it works.

Comment: For static values value needa to be enclosed with single quotes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the Integration Request, you can configure a static header value to be sent to the integration endpoint by putting the value inside of single quotes, e.g. `'my_static_header_value'`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a problem to put those hardcoded headers in the request body ? It not, you could just use a [template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html) (in the integration request screen) :

```
{
  "hardcoded_header": "$input.params('hardcoded_header')"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a problem.  I'm trying to pass an `Authorization` header with an oauth key.  I don't want to share this key with clients that have access to this service, since I will only provide a subset of access to users of this specific endpoint.

Comment: Actually, I wonder if there is a way to make that work.  I'll have to think about this some more when I have a moment.  Thanks, Francis.